# generating function for the number of partitions of n in which each odd part can occur any number of times but each even part can occur at most twice

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Write down the generating function for the number of partitions of $n$ in which each odd part can occur any number of times but each even part can occur at most twice. Apply algebra to this generating function to complete the following theorem:

The number of partitions of n in which each odd part can occur any number of times but each even part can occur at most twice is the number of partitions of n in which...

The generating function I've found for the first part is $$\prod_{k\geq1}\frac{(1+x^{2k})^2}{1-x^{2k-1}}$$
but I'm unsure how to start the second part, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The generating function for the first part is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{ (1+x^{2n}+x^{4n})}{1-x^{2n-1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The terms in the numerator deal with the even numbers occurring at most twice & the terms in the denominator deal with the odd numbers.

Now observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
  1+x^{2n}+x^{4n} = \frac{ 1-x^{6n} }{ 1-x^{2n} }.
\end{eqnarray*}
The generating function can be rewritten as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{n \geq 1   \text{  and  } 6 \nmid n }^{\infty}  \frac{ 1}{1-x^{n}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So it is the same as partitioning numbers whose parts are not multiples of $6$.

Comment: +1 Love it when generating functions yield a non-intuitive / obvious result.

Comment: @CalvinLin Really tough challenge ... set up a bijection between these two types of partitions ... Thank goodness for generating functions?

Comment: This is awesome!